# Output shows comma after every word after splitting a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

**"a few seconds agoDecember 31, 2019, GMT+5 11:23AM"**

When i `split` the above string to first 3 words, it shows like this: **[a, few, seconds]**

i want an output without commas and brackets just like:  **a few seconds**

i am using the following code:

```
var array = myString.split(' ', 3)
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is always useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```js
var myString="a few seconds agoDecember 31, 2019, GMT+5 11:23AM";
var array = myString.split(' ').slice(0,3).join(' ');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let arr = ["a", "few", "seconds"];
console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put the array of words back together after splitting:

```
const combined = array.join(' ');
```

```js
const myString = "a few seconds agoDecember 31, 2019, GMT+5 11:23AM";
var array = myString.split(' ', 3)
const combined = array.join(' ');
console.log(combined);
```

Or use `.match` and a regular expression instead, and avoid creating an unnecessary intermediate array:

```js
const myString = "a few seconds agoDecember 31, 2019, GMT+5 11:23AM";
const firstThreeWords = myString.match(/^(?:\S+ ){2}\S+/)[0];
console.log(firstThreeWords);
```

`^(?:\S+ ){2}\S+` means:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:\S+ ){2}` - Repeat, twice:

  - `(\S+ )` - Non-space characters, followed by a space
- `\S+` - Followed by more non-space characters